# Flooded by status messages in logcat (eclipse/android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, logcat

I sometimes get flooded by this strange message in logact:

"W/Settings(386): Setting location_providers_allowed has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only value."

The Problem is that those messages don't stop for a long time and I don't know how to stop them. It's always the same message and I already tried stopping and starting adb, restarting the device and eclipse.

Does anyone have any advice on this (except just clearing the log or living with it)?

PS: I have a 2.3.4 device with Tegra2 and nothing fancy.

Edit: Let me clarify: Why does this message suddenly start to appear in the tens of thousands ? It noticeably slows everything down and just tuning it out doesn't really help me all that much. I want to know what causes it and to make it stop.

Answer (score 0):

You can instruct logcat to filter on tags or log levels. Take a look at the [Reading and Writing Logs](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-log.html#filteringOutput) tutorial on the Android developer website for details.

Briefly, to only display logs of a certain TAG (any log level):

```
$ adb logcat MyTag:* *:S
```

Comment: that flood message will soon make logcat full and clear, so i cant read log message. Filter logcat doesn't help.